# Null pointer exception a la hora de rellenar un JcomboBox con objetos (clases de objetos generadas con hibernate)

Tags: java

A la hora de rellenar un JcomboBox con un objeto que me lo traigo direcctamente desde la clase generada con hibernate me salta un `null pointer exception`, las clases generadas estan bien (las he mirado mil veces)

```
package InterfazPrueba;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import generadas.Fabricante;
import generadas.Modelo;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class PruebaCombo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private List<Fabricante> lista;
    public SessionFactory sesion = null;
    public Session session = null;
    private JComboBox comboBox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PruebaCombo frame = new PruebaCombo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PruebaCombo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblModelos = new JLabel("Modelos");
        lblModelos.setBounds(71, 93, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblModelos);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(127, 89, 114, 22);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);
        rellenarComboBox();
    }

    public void rellenarComboBox() {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Fabricante");
        lista = query.list();
        for (Fabricante eq : lista) {
            comboBox.addItem(eq);
        }
    }
}
```

Si quereis las clases generadas por hibernate tambien las puedo pasar, pero de momento dejo esto.

Comment: Hola Adans, bienvenido. ¿Cuando inicializas `session`?

Comment: lois6b, me acabo de dar cuenta, Muchisimas gracias llevaba dos dias dandole vueltas. Los acabo de inicializar y funciona a la perfeccion, muchas gracias de verdad :)

Comment: @lois6b tu comentario puede convertirse en una respuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si, en el Chat pregunte qué consideraban... si hacerlo o no. luego lo hago, gracias

Comment: Deja tu comentario como respuesta, ya que están botando por cierre

Comment: @adans recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta, asi es como funciona el sitio. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

El problema está con la variable `session` que la usas sin haberla inicializado.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Fabricante");
```